# Error when Adding Menu to App - Xamarin c# Visual Studio

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to inflate an XML Menu inside my App, but i get the following error when I try to Deploy the App on an Emulator:

```
Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected end of document occurred
```

Also my XML is located in `Resources/menu/main`

**Inflate Menu Code:**

[image]

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:id="@+id/mnuAppLogo"
        android:title="logoHere"/>
  <item android:id="@+id/mnuAppName"
  android:title="App Name"/>
  <menu>
    <item android:id="@+id/submenuHelp"
    android:title="Help" />
    <item android:id="@+id/submenuExit"
    android:title="Exit" />
  </menu>
</menu>
```

Why is this?
Let me know if you need more code...

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1:**

I want to make the `logoHere and App Name` appear in spots `1 and 2` with the other 2 `Help and Exit` inside the Menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To create a "submenu", the elements must be included *within* an `item` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/mnuAppLogo" android:title="logoHere" />
    <item android:id="@+id/mnuAppName" android:title="App Name">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/submenuHelp" android:title="Help" />
            <item android:id="@+id/submenuExit" android:title="Exit" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

> How do I make it so that the First 2 (logoHere and App Name) are not in the "Hamburger Menu" and just on the Action Bar? The Help and Exit however will be inside the Menu.

You can use `showAsAction="never"` to always place the menu item in the overflow menu and `showAsAction="ifRoom"` to display it as an action bar button IF there is room for it.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/mnuAppLogo" showAsAction="ifRoom" android:title="logoHere" />
    <item android:id="@+id/mnuAppName" showAsAction="ifRoom" android:title="App Name" />
    <item android:id="@+id/submenuHelp" showAsAction="never" android:title="Help" />
    <item android:id="@+id/submenuExit" showAsAction="never" android:title="Exit" />
</menu>
```

Comment: How do I make it so that the First 2 `(logoHere and App Name)` are not in the "Hamburger Menu" and just on the Action Bar? 
The Help and Exit however will be inside the Menu.

Comment: Please see Update 1

Comment: @DEFALT You keep changing the original question/problem, you should create a new question.